# Variance of dependent vs independent variable

Tags: regression, machine-learning, linear

If the dependent variable Y follows normal distribution (N), which one has the higher variance (i.e. wider CI range), independent variable or dependent variable? Why?

Comment: It’s impossible to say without more information. What’s the context? What else is going on? $\text{//}$ We almost never care about the distribution of the dependent variable being normal. (I can’t think of a single time, even.) When we care about normality in a regression, it has to do with the error term.

Comment: Please give a more specific context.

Answer (score 1):

The dependent variable can have greater, smaller, or the same variance as the independent variable. Even if the underlying measurements are similar (e.g. units of length, or units of mass), we can make variance larger or smaller arbitrarily by changing the units,

To see why, consider that you can change the units of either variable. If $x$ has the same variance as $y$, then expressing either in different units, which rescale the data by a constant factor $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}\setminus \{1,-1\}$ can make the variance larger or smaller. This is because of how the variance works:

$$
\text{Var}(\alpha Z)=\alpha^2\text{Var}(Z)
$$

We can see immediately that for $\alpha \in \{-1,1\}$, the variance is the same.

So the fact that a variable is dependent or independent is not really important -- it can be made to have a larger or smaller variance in either case, for a specific choice of $\alpha$. An example of this is the choice to collect data  about one measurement in either meters or millimeters; the variance does not depend on whether the variable is dependent or independent, but it can be changed according to the units of measurement.